# How to sort Google results based on date

Tags: google-search

How can I sort Google results based on date that something is posted on some websites. Suppose, I want to install Ruby on Rails on El Captain(Mac OSX 10.11). Now, I don't want to write everything in Google i.e. I will just write how to "Install Ruby on Rails OSX"

and Google will automatically show me results for EL Captain and not older version of OSX(only blog posts or web posts which have recently posted about wikis on latest installation methods).

Another example could be,

How to remove user from Windows. Now, I don't want Google to show me old windows 7/8/8.1 methods. I just want to see latest posts which people have posted.

Is it possible to sort Google based on Timeline?

Comment: A tip from Web Apps: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80376/90497

Answer (score 1):

Google won't display results in a chronological way because it cannot determine the exact publishing date. Google displays and ranks results based on relevance.

However, you can set a custom date range in which your results need to be in. Use 'Search Tools' > 'Any time' > 'Custom range'

[image]

Comment: It doesn't have to; using the first index date works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try appending (space)**sort=date** to your search string.

For more information, Check out the "[Sort by Date](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/6329265#7a6d5b41-8792-4483-b5c4-dcfd7cbecf03)" section of Google's "Search Protocol Reference" chapter titled "[Request Format](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/6329265?hl=en&ref_topic=6329264)"

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://searchresearch1.blogspot.nl/2017/06/how-to-sort-google-search-results-by.html), simply append this to the end of your search URL: `&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/0,sbd:1`

Or manually specify a date range and order:

[image: Sort Google results by date]

Unfortunately, today it only appears to work with a single word, like "Thanos".